# Question about proving something in real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

when do we know to use direct proof or proof by contradiction? Please give me some tips.

Here, I'm not asking about a problem, just want to know what should i start with, and really-really want to understand how to prove something in real analysis

How do i know exactly that my proof is right? When sometimes i use contradiction (Reductio ad absurdum) for proving something, my teacher told me that my proof is false and too long, for example :

Let $S$ be a nonempty subset of $\Bbb R$ that is bounded  below.  Prove that $\inf S =-\sup\{ -s : s\in S\}.$

My teacher used direct proof for this. And told me that is enough to show this with direct proof instead of by contradiction.

And the second one is :

Show that there does not exist a rational number $s$ such that $s^2=6$.

And for this case, my teacher suggests me to use proof by contradiction. But why?
Is it impossoble to use direct proof?

Actually, my confuse in real analysis is just how do we proof something?, why does it can be? Why we use different way (direct and indirect proof) in each statement that needs to be proven.

Is memorize all theorems really useful? Besides, i'm bad in memorizing stuff.

Help me. Thanks.

Comment: there is not a general rule: just try different ways to make a proof, some would work, some other no. The art of prove something is an art, there are no "rules" to follow like a robot or a program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem follows directly from definitions; suppose $S\subset\mathbb R$ is bounded below, then it has a greatest lower bound $b$. Since $b\leqslant s$ for all $s\in S$, $-b\geqslant -s$ for all $s\in S$, and so $-S:=\{-s:s\in S\}$ is bounded above. Therefore $-S$ has a least upper bound $a$, and by definition, $a\leqslant -b$. Similarly, $a\geqslant s$ for all $s\in S$, so $-a\leqslant -s$ for all $s\in S$, which means that $-a$ is a lower bound for $S$. Therefore $-a\leqslant b$, or $a\geqslant -b$. From this we conclude that $b=-a$.

The second problem is different. In order to directly show that there does not exist a rational number $s$ such that $s^2=6$, we would have to show that for *all* rational numbers $s$, $s^2\ne 6$. Now there are (countably) infinitely many rational numbers, so how would we go about doing this? We certainly don't have infinite time to write the proof! But if instead we assume that there *is* a rational number $s$ such that $s^2=6$, then we know that $s=\frac pq$ for some integers $p,q$ such that $q>0$ and $p$ and $q$ are coprime. So $6 = \frac{p^2}{q^2}$, and hence $p^2=6q^2$. It follows that $p^2$ is even since an even integer (i.e. $6$) multiplied by any other integer is even. Now, an odd number times an odd number is an odd number, so $p$ itself must be even. Let $p=2k$, then we have $(2k)^2=6q^2$, hence $4k^2 = 6q^2$, hence $2k^2 = 3q^2$. This shows that $3q^2$ is even, and since $3$ is odd, it must be that $q^2$ is even. But this means that $q$ itself is even, so both $p$ and $q$ are even. This contradicts our assumption that $p$ and $q$ are coprime.

As you read and write proofs over and over, you begin to notice patterns and see which method of proof might work better than another for a particular problem. This is just something that you gain with experience.

Finally, if you are bad at memorizing theorems, then don't! *Understand* them instead. Being able to prove a theorem is far more useful than being able to recite the result.